# What does Non-circumvention actually mean?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, contracts

A staffing firm offer included a **Non-Circumvention** paragraph basically including the following:

> For the period of employment and 12 months after termination, the
>   employee will not engage in the provision of any service to any
>   company client where employee performed work except on behalf of our
>   staffing company.

Can someone explain what this exactly means to the employee?

Comment: Lawyers are always good places to start for translating contracts.

Comment: This is a common clause in many contracts.  It does not require a lawyer to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about understanding something written in English, thus it's an English language question more so than a workplace one.

Comment: @Dukeling It's not exactly basic English usage and as IDrinkandIKnowThings, it's a common clause among many contracts where you provide services to external companies, but could be something the OP hasn't come across before. This is an entirely relevant and answerable quesiton to the workplace. The only close reason I would think of, is a duplicate, but can't find one for now

Comment: @Draken IMO you only need a firm grasp of the English language to understand what this clause means. A non-compete clause, for example, could go beyond English in that it may not be clear what exactly "competing" means in the business world, and a more specific "does X fall under this clause", that would be workplace related (but both of those would presumably be a question for a lawyer). This appears to follow roughly the same argument as for why general hardware and software questions are off topic on [so].

Answer (score 19):

This basically means that you won't do any work for a client of the company that you worked for for at least a year after leaving the company.

From the staffing firm's standpoint, what they are trying to prevent is the contractor (you) and the client (whoever you end up actually doing work for) deciding that they can contract directly and cut out the staffing firm from their cut.  The staffing firm expends time and effort finding openings, finding contractors, managing relationships, etc. that they make up over time by taking a cut from the hourly wage.  If the client and the contractor decide to bypass the staffing firm, that destroys the economics of the staffing firm and turns them into a very poorly paid headhunter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Justin. I understand this, however, staffing firms are huge and have hundreds of companies as connections, making the employee vulnerable to being `held hostage`, and saying something like `if you applied to any company in this list of 500 companies in this area, then they are our clients and you must apply through us`. Another thing is, why the 12month period if the contract length is only 3 months, wouldn't they make enough money off the contract already?

Comment: In other words, what if the company decides to hire the employee directly after 8 months, why is the staffing firm still in the picture if they already made money their cut off the 3 month contract?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend - The restriction is only on those clients that you did work for (which is presumably much smaller than 500 companies).  I'd wager that the 12 month limit is boilerplate pegged to the maximum limit that would generally be allowed in the contract's juristiction.  Potentially, it's excessive for a 3 month contract if there is no potential for renewal (that's a matter for negotiation).

Comment: @AnchovyLegend - There is no guarantee that the staffing firm would break even on a 3 month contract (they might, of course, but might not).  They assume that a certain fraction of contracts will get renewed and a certain fraction will last long enough to break even while a certain fraction will not.  As long as the excess from the winners cover the shortfall from the losers, the staffing firm makes money.

Comment: @JustinCave - Staffing firms are not in the business of losing money on contracts.  They might eat one contract to make a client happy but chances are they are making money even on the 3 month contract.

Comment: @Chad - Depends on how you account for the various overheads.  They're certainly making less on a 3 month contract than, say, a headhunter would make filling the same opening (hence the need for the non-circumvention clause).

Comment: @JustinCave - makes less != losing money

Comment: @Chad - Again, it depends on how you account for the overheads.  Are they making revenue?  Of course.  Does that revenue pay for all the overheads of finding the client, finding the contractor, placing the contractor, maintaining the relationship with the client, handling the invoicing, etc.?  Maybe, maybe not.  Headhunters aren't operating with huge profit margins so if you're generating much less revenue and incurring the same level of costs as a staffing firm, you're not going to be in business long.

Comment: The overhead is not the contractors problem and it has no bearing on whether the contract makes money or not.  simply are they getting more money for the time that the contractor spends at the client than they have to pay to employ the contractor...  the formula is usually R-Rc*1.45 = P  where R = rate paid to company Rc = rate paid to contractor and P = gross profit per pay period

Comment: But they used the wrong term if you google "Non-Circumvention" its not about working for clients its more a trade secrets issue.